# Inherit a Blazor component to a MudBlazor component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, mudblazor

I need to create a new table component to reuse it on my application pages and I want to use MudTable from MudBlazor (With Typescript and React, I can do it).

I'm trying to inherit the MudTable from MudBlazor to my Table component class:

*Table.razor*

```
@typeparam T
@inherits MudTable<T>

<div class="table-component">
    <MudTable
        T="@T"
    >

    </MudTable>
</div>
```

*Table.razor.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using MudBlazor;

namespace ticketsapp.Components.Table
{
    public partial class Table<T>: MudTable<T>
    {
    }
}
```

And I add Attributes param to fill MudTable missing attributes

*Table.razor.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using MudBlazor;

namespace ticketsapp.Components.Table
{
    public partial class Table<T>: MudTable<T>
    {
        #region "PARAMETERS"

        [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region "FUNCTIONS"

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Table.razor

```
@typeparam T
@inherits MudTable<T>

<div class="table-component">
    <MudTable
        T="@T"
        @attributes="@Attributes"
    >

    </MudTable>
</div>
```

But when I compile I see navigator console a message:

> crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Multiple properties were found on component type
> 'ticketsapp.Components.Table.Table`1[[ticketsapp.Models.Ticket, ticketsapp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with 'ParameterAttribute.CaptureUnmatchedValues'. Only a single property per type can use 'ParameterAttribute.CaptureUnmatchedValues'. Properties: Attributes UserAttributes System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple properties were found on component type 'ticketsapp.Components.Table.Table`1[[ticketsapp.Models.Ticket,
> ticketsapp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
> with 'ParameterAttribute.CaptureUnmatchedValues'. Only a single
> property per type can use 'ParameterAttribute.CaptureUnmatchedValues'.
> Properties: Attributes UserAttributes    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.ThrowForMultipleCaptureUnmatchedValuesParameters(Type
> targetType)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.WritersForType..ctor(Type
> targetType)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView&
> parameters, Object target)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView.SetParameterProperties(Object
> target)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView
> parameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView
> directAndCascadingParameters)

I'm new in blazor and I don't know if exists another correct way to do it this.

Answer (score 2):

`MudTable` already has a property called `UserAttributes` with `[Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]` attribute. Your component inherits from MudTable so you can't declare a second property with this attribute. You can simply use the property from base class.

```
@typeparam T
@inherits MudTable<T>

<div class="table-component">
    <MudTable
        T="@T"
        @attributes="@base.UserAttributes"
    >

    </MudTable>
</div>
```